# SWIFTUI increase the quantity of a product in all three views

Tags: swift, swiftui, product, cart, product-quantity

I need to click on the + or - button and change the quantity, the problem is that with this code the quantity always resets to zero,
I can't increase it and memorize it, I also tried using the product.quantity += 1 in each button of each view, but at that point HOME works but if I change the quantity from CART then it doesn't update it in HOME.
while if I put product.quantity in the addTo Cart function, it tells mehelp me I tried them all please "(Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'product' is a 'let' constant)"
in each view I would like to change the quantity and update it on both
I also need to add only one item to the cart with the quantity, but since I can't read the quantity, I add more all the same

I enclose the pictures of the HOME and CART
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzy4J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/metgt.png)

```
struct Product: Identifiable,Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var categoria: ProductType
    var codice: String
    var descrizione: String = ""
    var prezzo: String
    var immagine: String = ""
    var quantity: Int = 1
}
```

```
class SharedDataModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cartProducts: [Product] = []
    
    func addToCart(product: Product) {
        if let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(of: product) {
            cartProducts[index].quantity += 1 //it doesn't register the quantity for me and it always resets it to zero
        }else {
            cartProducts.append(product)
        }
    }

    func removeFromCart(product: Product) {
        guard let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(of: product) else {return}
        if cartProducts[index].quantity > 1 {
            cartProducts[index].quantity -= 1
        }else {
            cartProducts.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
```

```
struct ProductCardView: View{
    
    @Binding var product: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    
    var body: some View{

                Button (action: {
                    sharedData.removeFromCart(product: product)
                } , label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                })
                Text("\(product.quantity-1)") //here i need to read the current quantity
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 30)
                Button(action: {
                    sharedData.addToCart(product: product)
                } , label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                })
    }
}
```

```
struct CardView: View{

    @Binding var product: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
 
                    Button {
                    sharedData.removeFromCart(product: product)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "minus")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .background(Color("Quantity"))
                            .cornerRadius(4)
                    }

                    Text("\(product.quantita)")//here i need to read the current quantity
                        .font(.custom(customFont, size: 14))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    Button {
                    sharedData.addToCart(product: product)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .background(Color("Quantity"))
                            .cornerRadius(4)
    }
}
```

I really need your help, I tried them all, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small example to build a similar scenario. I was able to update the quantities of individual of products. Let me know if it helps!

```
import SwiftUI

struct Product: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    var quantity: Int
}

class StoreModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cartProducts: [Product] = []
    
    func populateProducts() {
        cartProducts = [Product(title: "Product 1", quantity: 0), Product(title: "Product 2", quantity: 0)]
    }
        
    func addToCart(_ product: Product) {
        
        guard let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(where: { p in
            p.id == product.id
        }) else { return }
        
        cartProducts[index].quantity += 1
    }
    
    func removeFromCart(_ product: Product) {
        
        guard let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(where: { p in
            p.id == product.id
        }) else { return }
                
        cartProducts[index].quantity -= 1
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var storeModel: StoreModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List(storeModel.cartProducts) { product in
            HStack {
                Text(product.title)
                Button("+") {
                    storeModel.addToCart(product)
                }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                Button("-") {
                    storeModel.removeFromCart(product)
                }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .tint(.red)
                
                Text("\(product.quantity)")
            }
        }.task {
            storeModel.populateProducts()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(StoreModel())
    }
}
```

If you are running on a simulator then make sure to inject StoreModel as an EnvironmentObject to the root view of your application.

```
@main
struct LearnApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(StoreModel())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, i tried to do a copy paste of your code adding a view, it always resets the amount as soon as i change view!!

Comment: I rewrote the code in a post down

Comment: the problem is when it changes view it resets the count

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for the reply, i tried to do a copy paste of your code adding a view, it always resets the amount as soon as i change view!!

```
import SwiftUI

struct Product: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    var quantity: Int
}

class StoreModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cartProducts: [Product] = []
    
    func populateProducts() {
        cartProducts = [Product(title: "Product 1", quantity: 0), Product(title: "Product 2", quantity: 0)]
    }
        
    func addToCart(_ product: Product) {
        
        guard let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(where: { p in
            p.id == product.id
        }) else { return }
        
        cartProducts[index].quantity += 1
        
        print(cartProducts)
        print(product.quantity)
    }
    
    func removeFromCart(_ product: Product) {
        
        guard let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(where: { p in
            p.id == product.id
        }) else { return }
                
        cartProducts[index].quantity -= 1
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var storeModel: StoreModel
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List(storeModel.cartProducts) { product in //Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type StoreModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for StoreModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view
                    HStack {
                        Text(product.title)
                        Button("+") {
                            storeModel.addToCart(product)
                        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        Button("-") {
                            storeModel.removeFromCart(product)
                        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                            .tint(.red)
                        
                        Text("\(product.quantity)")
                    }
                }.task {
                    storeModel.populateProducts()
            }
                .navigationTitle(Text("Cart"))
                .toolbar {
                    NavigationLink{
                        Cart()
                            .environmentObject(StoreModel())
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "cart")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct Cart: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var storeModel: StoreModel
    
    var body: some View {

            List(storeModel.cartProducts) { product in
                HStack {
                    Text(product.title)
                    Button("+") {
                        storeModel.addToCart(product)
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    Button("-") {
                        storeModel.removeFromCart(product)
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        .tint(.red)
                    
                    Text("\(product.quantity)")
                    
                }
            }.task {
                storeModel.populateProducts()
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(StoreModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reset the count when you change the view". The code you pasted above works perfectly without any issues. If you are not running in Xcode Previews then make sure to inject environment object to your root view inside your App file. Check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, thanks to you I understood where the error is, if you can solve it for me I would be grateful

Comment: @main
struct LearnApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(StoreModel())
        }
    }
}

Comment: posted my code if you can help me how to solve it I would be grateful, as you explained to me I understood but I can't adapt it to my code, since it has an array of products filtered by category!!

Comment: you would need a function that associates the quantity with the product id and not with the index

Answer (score 0):

I should be able to increment e decrement the quantity in the FilteredProducts array, but being an unpopulated array I can't do it, and as if it couldn't find the index

```
struct Product: Identifiable,Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var categoria: ProductType
    var codice: String
    var descrizione: String = ""
    var prezzo: String
    var immagine: String = ""
    var quantita: Int = 0
}

enum ProductType: String,CaseIterable{
    case Croci = "Croci"
    case Medaglie = "Medaglie"
    case Cuori = "Cuori"
    case Stelle = "Stelle"
}
```

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var productType: ProductType = .Croci

    @Published var products: [Product] = [Product(categoria: .Croci, codice: "P20-10A", prezzo: "10€",immagine: "P20-10A"),
        Product(categoria: .Croci, codice: "P20-10N", prezzo: "11€",immagine: "P20-10N"),]
        
    @Published var filteredProducts: [Product] = []
    init(){
        filterProductByType()
        
        searchCancellable = $searchText.removeDuplicates()
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { str in
                if str != ""{
                    self.filterProductBySearch()
                }
                else{
                    self.searchedProducts = nil
                }
            })
    }
    
    func incrementQuantityFiltered(_ product: Product) {
        
        guard let index = products.firstIndex(where: { p in
            p.id == product.id
        }) else { return }
        
        products[index].quantita += 1
    }
    
    func decrementQuantityFiltered(_ product: Product) {
        
        guard let index = products.firstIndex(where: { p in
            p.id == product.id
        }) else { return }
                
        products[index].quantita -= 1
    }
    
    func filterProductByType(){
        
        // Filtering Product By Product Type...
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            
            let results = self.products
            // Since it will require more memory so were using lazy to perform more...
                .lazy
                .filter { product in
                    
                    return product.categoria == self.productType
                }
            // Limiting result...
                
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                self.filteredProducts = results.compactMap({ product in
                    return product
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Home: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    @StateObject var homeData: HomeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

                        ForEach($homeData.filteredProducts){$product in
                            
            ProductCardView(product: $product,homeData: HomeViewModel())
}
}
```

```
struct ProductCardView: View{
    
    @Binding var product: Product
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    @ObservedObject var homeData: HomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View{

            HStack (spacing: 0){
                Text(product.codice)
                
                Text(product.prezzo)
}
                Button (action: {
                    homeData.decrementQuantityFiltered(product)
                } , label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                })
                Text("\(product.quantita)")
                Button(action: {
                    homeData.incrementQuantityFiltered(product)
                } , label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                })
```

Comment: It looks like you're posting answers with new non-working code as though it's a conversation.  In the future, it might be a good idea to update or append to your original question content instead of adding new answers then continuing the conversation in either the question comments or other non-working answer's comments. Hopefully this will help attract more people to new questions you ask and make the general flow easier to understand :-)